# PrintWriter : java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, printwriter

Without pasting the entire code here, the line where the exception keeps happening is :

```
PrintWriter prtwrt = new PrintWriter(new File(directoryName+File.separator+stud.getIndex()+".txt"));
```

I have consulted the internet, and the books I have on Java, and by all logic it ought to work, but it doesn't. Can someone explain as to why it doesn't work, or perhaps propose a solution?

Stacktrace :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: students\0096-03.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at StudentsManager.main(StudentsManager.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

Also, directoryName, as the name implies, is the name of the directory where the file should be created. In this case it is "students".

Comment: and what is `directoryName` ?? Also paste whole exception with stacktrace

Comment: It doesn't work because The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @Antoniossss edited the question

Comment: The `students` directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

So lets have

```
File f=new File(directoryName+File.separator+stud.getIndex()+".txt");
```

First lets check if path exists and create dir tree if it does not:

```
if(!f.getParentFile().exists()) f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

now you can try to create Writer

```
PrintWriter prtwrt = new PrintWriter(f);
```

`PrintWriter` should create new file if not yet exists; If for some reasons it will not work, create file beforeheand with `f.createNewFile()`

All together it must work.

Answer (score 0):

try to enter the full path to the file because you might enter a relative path.

If you want to check if you have found the file try the following code:

```
File file  = new File(...);
if(!file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File not found!");
    return;
}
```